# how to use long regex strings in php

Tags: php, regex, regexbuddy

i have this regex string that i got from a website to pull emails from a file:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Ive tested it in regex buddy ( regex testing software ) and it works!

when i copy and paste the regex from regex buddy to my php file, i have to escape 2 `"` characters to make the regex form a valid string in php.

in php i use it like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents(/* URL TO GET */);

$email_pattern = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])";

$matches = array();

if ( preg_match_all ( $email_pattern, $file, $matches ))
{
    echo print_r($matches, true);
}
```

but i get this warning!?!?

```
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '@'
```

however this regex works in regex buddy?

Where am i going wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things:

step 1:

You need to put delimiters ( the / before and after the regex, so that you may add modifier ):

```
$email_pattern = "/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/";
```

step2:

And as your in a PHP string, you'll need to escape all the special character ( like \ that must become \\ , and $ that would become \$ , etc... )

So the escape to include the regex in a PHP String should look like this:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\\\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\\\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])
```

And you also have to escape /, as we use that caracter for the delimiter of the first step. So we need the regex to see \/, but as we express the regex in a php string, we will replace / by \\/

If I'm right *-- usually I use regex buddy too to do the conversion with the PHP export tool, but now I don't have it so I've done it by hand--* it should give something ***LIKE*** this:

```
$email_pattern = '/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/';
```

I would also suggest that you put the string inside single quote.

Comment: I copy and pasted your answer and got this error: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '='. but the equals sign is already escaped? I also used preg_quote to auto escape regex special chars but them i got the error: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: copy and pasted my anwser for the step 1, but did you escape as I mentionned in the step 2 ?

Comment: ill try that now, to \ becomes \\ and $ becomes \$ but are there any more i should be aware of? is there a list online or something?

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch: escape also the slashes `\/`

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch I see you might have trouble with understanding the basic of strings, I've just updated my answer, I hope it will help you a bit more this time :)

Comment: ```'/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/'```  is what RegexBuddy comes up with for me.  You're goin' a bit overboard with the backslashes!

Comment: Well thanks, I didn't have the tool right now ( under osX ), I'll update the answer with that. (At first, I did an addslashes() to get the regex, so extra character got backslashed... )

Answer (score 0):

I tried and...

Single quotes will give an error...

Use double quotes and the {} as delimiters // gives an error also

Comment: Single quote would works, and / delimiter would not give error if you escape thoses in the regex. Right now even the $ is interpreted because of the double quote. with single quote, almost only \ and ' would need to be escaped.

Comment: your right! PHP will be fine, but not the regexp for email check

Comment: You have to escape FOR php, THEN for the regex, so you might have quadruple backslashes in some case, but the double quote just make the problem harder.